# Laravel Query Builder, How does it work

Tags: php, laravel

Sorry for this very noob question. I started PHP for almost 1 months. I don't have any background in programming. Without using a framework. A friend of mine lets me work with him on a project. which uses a php it had a framework which was built by them.  Since their team lead decided to pick a new framework, which was laravel and rewrite the whole project. Luckily he still let me join them. I've been working only on the small stuff in the project. I haven't touched any database related during my work with them.  after a week I had to go back to my home town so I can't work with them anymore. Since then I keep reading the laravel documentation. And tried database. I stumbled on this eloquent which builds query from class names or method name. I was so confused. But I don't know what to search for or how does this work. I scanned the code and hell it was so advance I give up. I can't sleep on how to make this. so if any of you could give me an example how this works I would be very happy.

```
class User extends Model
{

}
```

which when called like this

```
User::all()
```

it will give some data. but how.? it this part of php? All I see about php mysql is about pdo. I can't find any examples like this

Comment: There is a lot of 'magic' going on in laravel. From connecting to database, to creating queries. Eloquent is essentially an ORM. The `all()` is a shortcut to calling `select * from user` and returns an 'array'. You should start from scratch, because Laravel introduces concepts that inherently natural to the framework. [Check out laracasts for indepth walkthroughs.](https://laracasts.com/)

Comment: If you are a beginner in programming it could be difficult to grasp these concepts: for a beginner the best way to approach would be: first learn php basic stuff, then learn object oriented programming, then learn a framework and the basics of MVC. I know that probably you don't have time for all of this now, but jumping into a framework with no knowledge of the basics could be difficult for everyone

Comment: I read some oop for php. and when I refer to laravel. my mind goes to. 'what the heck. where arel this comming from'.

Comment: if this some kind of magic. I think I need to enroll on any online school.

Comment: Laravel uses intensively magic methods, so it could be difficult understanding the internals. Keep in mind that, however, a beginner should firstly read and understand the docs, so he could start using the framework righ away. Understanding the internals is a more advanced task, and it's not mandatory in order to use the framework

Comment: feel free to delete this question if I'm wasting anyones time. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

A model in laravel is linked to a snake cased table. This means that a `User` model maps to a `users` table but this can be overwritten by adding this in your model class

`protected $table == "my_custom_table_name"`

When you use `User:all()` It will return all the records in the `users` table. It simply runs `select * from users` beneath it.

The `all()` method is defined in the extended `model class`. You can check it out to understand how laravel automagically does stuff.

Comment: unfortunately, I can't find the all() method on the one it extends.

Comment: `all()` is defined in an Illuminate package.
Checkout `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php`

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L640

Comment: Next question will be 'how does laravel know how to use this model class'. It's better to refer him back to the scratchpad.

Comment: oh my. This is why I can't find it. i use find and put all()

Comment: what's scratchpad?

Comment: Learn all the basics of PHP. OOP & MVC. Then check out http://www.laracasts.com (beginner to advanced guide on laravel). Finally, go to http://www.phptherightway.com/ to understand the internals of how laravel does all that magic & also [PSR](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/) for coding standards